# How to plot a small-scale topographic map with matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I am plotting a insar image and want to add some geologic information to it. That is, I want to **combine my image** (what I’ve done, a picture made by matplotlib, in latitude and longitude coordinate) **with topography**.

At first I want to use the **Basemap** in the **matplotlib toolkit** to plot the topographic basemap, for I plot the satellite image using matplotlib. I found something that looked like just what I want in the basemap module:

Draw an **etopo** relief image: 
[http://matplotlib.org/basemap/users/geography.html][2]
(Sorry but I do not have reputation to post an image as a beginner.)

I guess I just need to shift the center. So I just imitated the script in the given example and made a little change to the coordinate:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# setup Lambert Conformal basemap.
# set resolution=None to skip processing of boundary datasets.
m = Basemap(projection='cyl',llcrnrlon=-118.5,llcrnrlat=33.15,urcrnrlon=-117.15,urcrnrlat=34.5,\
            resolution='f')
m.shadedrelief()
plt.show()
```

Then I got an ugly,  blurred picture.

Later I found out the reason by searching online. Default image size is 5400x2700, which makes it slow to plot and vague in small-scale maps. So it seems an incorrect way to do this.

Is that anyway to get a high resolution topographic basemap using matplotlib? Must I begin to learn GMT? Please help me...

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this but change the epsg from your zone. This codes are at 
http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/

```html
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

map = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-76.5,llcrnrlat=7., urcrnrlon=-75.9,urcrnrlat=7.5, resolution = 'h', epsg=3115)
map.arcgisimage(service='Specialty/DeLorme_World_Base_Map', xpixels = 1500, verbose= True)
#map.arcgisimage(service='NatGeo_World_Map', xpixels = 2000, verbose= False)
plt.show()
plt.close()
```